# Expire JMS message on message id

Tags: jms

I have posted a message on topic. After posting message, I have Message ID. Now using this Message ID, can I change the JMS Message Expiration?

I have Andes Broker Engine.

Scenario : Suppose mistakenly I have sent a message to a topic and before subscriber becomes active and receives message I want to Expire the message.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do really, remove the message?
Anyway, what you should do is to read it out using a [jms selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html#bncer) specifying the message id. Then I don't see a point in changing the expire header and publish it again since you just want to remove it, but you can of course do that as well for whatever reason.